# sed with several matches

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, sed

The two "sed lines" only differ by a "\n" below..
How can i get this output [no new line before the `</pre>`]? [ http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ED34jvtF ]:
`.`
`.`
`something3`
`</pre>`
`something4`
`.`
`.`


`$ echo -e 'something1\nsomething2\nsomething3\n\n</pre>\nsomething4\nsomething5'; echo "######################################"; echo -e 'something1\nsomething2\nsomething3\n\n</pre>\nsomething4\nsomething5' | sed -e N -e N -e "s#\n</pre>#</pre>#g" -e P -e D`
`something1`
`something2`
`something3`

`</pre>`
`something4`
`something5`
`######################################`
`something1`
`something2`
`something3</pre>`
`something4`
`something5`
`$`
`$ echo -e 'something1\nsomething2\nsomething3\n\n</pre>\nsomething4\nsomething5' | sed -e N -e N -e "s#\n</pre>#\n</pre>#g" -e P -e D`
`something1`
`something2`
`something3`

`</pre>`
`something4`
`something5`
`$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
sed 's|\(.\+\)\(</pre>\)$|\1\n\2|;t;N;\|\n</pre>$|s|^[[:blank:]]*\n||;P;D' inputfile
```

The result:

```
something1
something2
something3
</pre>
something4
something5
######################################
something1
something2
something3
</pre>
something4
something5
```

Notice that both instances of `</pre>` are on a line by themselves without a preceding blank line.

**Edit:** Fixed a problem with deleting the wrong lines.

Comment: hey, it worked!!:) no new line before the pre http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ywc16UMk THANK YOU!! god bless the open source community:)

Comment: oops: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0fV15Yg2 it deletes not just the empty lines before `</pre>` - because it deletes one line before it. i only need to delete the _empty_ line before `</pre>`! but thank you!

Comment: @user: Sorry about that, try the revised version.

Comment: @user: If you found this answer useful, please mark it as accepted (you can also upvote it if you like).